# Flickering screen after lock - started at ubuntu 5.13.0.27, still in 5.13.0.28 - Hard reset required

Tags: screen

I started having this issue on my HP Probook with 5.13.0.27, the problem happens when I lock my laptop (does NOT restore - flickering screen - had to hard reboot).

Here is what I got on my hw:

*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Renoir
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
version: c4
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
resources: irq:46 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0600000-e067ffff

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; you mention Ubuntu and a kernel version (a kernel that is used by multiple releases), so some options that may exist for you may also not exist; depending on details you've not yet provided (ie. what product/release are you using?)   *You mention hard reset; did a clean SysRq reset command work to resolve? or are using using a product/release where that's not possible?  Could you switch to text terminal & explore etc*

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the issue? I still have the same in April, 2022, have to use old kernel 5.11.
None of 5.13's kernels work - 5.13.27, 5.13.28, 5.13.37, 5.13.39

HP-17 laptop, AMD Radeon Vega card

UPD: I was able to solve the issue by manually updating linux-firmware-1.187.26 package as described here
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-firmware_1.187.26_all.deb